# Monitor HTTP NetBeans

Tags: web-services, rest, http, netbeans

Firstly I had a problem with the `antiJARLocking` attribute that was showing an error in the console:

WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-69] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule] {Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.

But I commented this part and it does not appear anymore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/DivulgueAqui"/>
<!-- antiJARLocking="true" -->
```

Then got a bug with the netbeans monitor

Showing this error:

```
The request can not be recorded most likely because the NetBeans HTTP Monitor module is disabled.
```

But in my last tests to get this error and put here for you this did not happen!

When I'm trying to run the web service it returns me code 500.

The information is arriving in the method and insert but when it arrives in the dao.insert (u);
The service stops working

```
    @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("usuario/inserir")
public String insertUsuario(String json){

    UsuarioDao dao = new UsuarioDao();
    Usuario u = new Usuario();

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();  

    String nome;
    String email;
    String senha;

       try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);

            nome = (String) jsonObject.get("nome");
            email = (String)jsonObject.get("email");
            senha = (String) jsonObject.get("senha");

            u.setNome(nome);
            u.setEmail(email);
            u.setSenha(senha);

            dao.inserir(u);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("WS.webService.insertUsuario()" + ex);
            Logger.getLogger(webService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
     return null;
```

}

My question is. How do I solve this problem?